# Optimizing mySQL LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, join

I have a trips table where finished trips have a transaction id in trips.txnPNR.

I have a driver_contacts table which references trips.id.

I have to find out if there are trips where trips.txnPNR is set but which are not represented by a row with that id in driver_contacts.trip.

I am successfully locating these trips with this JOIN but apparently it is very memory intensive.

```
SELECT
 trips.id,
 driver_contacts.trip
FROM trips
LEFT JOIN driver_contacts ON trips.id = driver_contacts.trip WHERE trips.`tripDropoff` > '2014-10-24 15:15:25'
AND driver_contacts.trip IS NULL
AND TRIM(trips.txnPNR) != ''
```

My colleague is recommending a change to the much faster

```
SELECT
 24hourTrips.id,
 driver_contacts_null.trip
FROM (SELECT id,txnPNR FROM trips WHERE trips.`tripDropoff` > now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND
TRIM(txnPNR) != '') AS 24hourTrips
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM driver_contacts where driver_contacts.trip IS NULL) AS driver_contacts_null ON 24hourTrips.id = driver_contacts_null.trip
```

BUT that query gets all the trips regardless of whether they have a row in driver_contacts.

What would be a less intensive lookup for all trips rows whose id is not in driver_contacts.trip?

Comment: Does the second query solve the problem, in spite of your intensiveness objections?

Comment: @RobertHarvey - the second query uses very few resources but returns incorrect data.  It returns trips from last 24 hours which already have a driver_contacts row.

Comment: First query is costly but correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution!  Returns in under a second so everyone is happy.

```
SELECT
24hourTrips.id,
driver_contacts.trip
FROM (SELECT id,txnPNR FROM trips WHERE trips.`tripDropoff` > now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND
TRIM(txnPNR) != '') AS 24hourTrips
LEFT OUTER JOIN driver_contacts ON 24hourTrips.id = driver_contacts.trip WHERE driver_contacts.trip IS NULL AND TRIM(24hourTrips.txnPNR) != ''
```